# Closing a Java Socket safely without server side exceptions

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

What is the Safest way to close a socket connection from client side. Shutdown inputs first or close() the connection straight away?

Comment: It depends on the protocol: which side is expected to do what and when.

Comment: You can have protocol which sends a "hangup" or "bye" messgae and then there should be no surprises.

Comment: The client is expected to close down the socket when he hasn't requested anything from the server. I am using the basic Java net package and the protocol is TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your protocol (top of TCP) does not contain any message/handshake for closing a session, then you must do it by closing TCP connection.

There are two ways to close a TCP connection:

- graceful: uses TCP SYN, all undelivered data is transferred (tried). `read()` of `InputStream` returns -1;
- ungraceful: uses TCP RST, all undelivered data is discarded. `read()` of `InputStream` throws an exception.

Both can be done in java with close() function of Socket.
Graceful is the default. Ungraceful, if `setsolinger(true,0);` is done before the close().

Comment: Sorry you mentioned how to do 'ungraceful'. It is a singularly useless feature, much abused and best avoided.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the socket already shuts down both input and output. You don't need to do either of those explicitly.